# Glimpse is not logging Nhibernate queries (mvc3)

Tags: nhibernate, glimpse

I have installed glimpse in my visual studio environment.
all working fine except nhibernate...

this is how I pass the factory:

```
factory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
NHibernate.Glimpse.Plugin.RegisterSessionFactory(factory);
```

this is my relevant sections in the web config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="nhibernate-logger" value="NHibernate.Glimpse.LoggerFactory, NHibernate.Glimpse" />
    <add key="NHibernate.Glimpse.Loggers" value="command" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

    <!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
        <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> -->
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">

  </glimpse>
</configuration>
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the [NHibernate.Glimpse NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Glimpse)?

The [Glimpse.Ado NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Ado) only adds ADO profiling when used in combination with `DbProviderFactory`

Comment: Tanks, but I did. I actually followed the tutorials on the site